# Why my function doesn't get my int var?! AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function

I have a trouble. I got my dear `var myVar:int` and an `arr:Array`. I want to use them to execute my function.
`s1` and `indice1` are array and integer values as I was defined in my program.

```
getIndex(s1, indice1);

function getIndex(arr:Array, index:int = 0):void {
    for (var n:int = 0; n <= arr.length; n++) {
        if (String(arr[n]).indexOf(">") >= 0) {
            index = n;
            trace(n);
            arr[n] = String(arr[n]).substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

now i get rigth results for my Array but i have a 0 for my index var.

Can someone help me?

I mean i need a  dynamic way to assing index values of differents arrays to diferents indices so I can use my function to retrieve and index and save it for any Array I have

Comment: Can you explain what you expect your function to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty unclear.

However, to answer (what I **THINK** you are asking),
You can not access variable `index` outside of the function. This is because the type `int` is not saved as a reference in AS3. To get `index` outside, you will have to do either of the following:

a) Assign the value of index to a global variable e.g.:

```
var gIndex:int;

function getIndex(arr:Array,index:int = 0):void{
    //function contents
    gIndex=index;    
}
//This way you can access index as gIndex;
```

b) Return the variable `index` from the function

```
function getIndex(arr:Array,index:int = 0):int{
    //function contents
    return index;    
}

//this way you can access index as getIndex(s1, indice1);
```

Comment: If u read prev comments I explain exactly the problem, and find that I already solve it, just w18 for 8 hours to can answer cuz my reputation isn't 100 or more.

Comment: It's a pretty nice answer, but I really don't understand why u create an atribute index:int for da function to not even use it like one. I mean, if i want to return an n value to diferents index u can't, cuz ure returning n and assingning it to gIndex all time, so it isn't a dynamic way.

Comment: Ah, well yes, the index parameter is not required, but I just copied your function signature from your question, so....

Answer (score 0):

Your search string is available in `arr[0]` So that it returns `0`.

Comment: s1[0] is contains the string "<".

Comment: 0,0,2,-1,3,7,>1,2,-3,0,0 are the values for s1:Array, so ">" is on 6 position. now, if i trace(n); i got 6, but if I asing index = n; index takes 0 value

Comment: I think... u are tracing the `index` value before assign to `n` var.

Comment: nope. bro, I just trace n after I assing n value to index

     index = n;
     trace("position: "+n+", index: "+index);

I get "position 6, index: 0

Comment: But I got `6`. I don't know.. wr u made the mistake.

Comment: I need indice1 to take da value of n, cuz that I create index atribute to my function so i can assing n value to any int var, but whe I assing n to index atribute it is 0 and if I print n flash print me 6 that value is the one I want on index.

Comment: I already answer it bro. thanks anyway. I have to w8 8 hours to can answer it by my self, so I will in 8 hours =P.

I just return "n" value from my function and adding it to indice1 like this:

indice1 = getIndex(s1);

Comment: I didn't get you and u haven't explained well too.. Just give a brief for 'executing the program for wt?'. If I can't then someone will help u...

Comment: It's hard to explain clearly what I want in english, so sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solve it.

Well it isn't what I want to but look.

I decided to return n value from my function and assing it to my var.

```
indice1 = getIndex(s1);

function getIndex(arr:Array){

    for(var n:int=0; n<= arr.length; n++){

   if( String(arr[n]).indexOf(">") >= 0){ 

    return n;                          
    arr[n]= String(arr[n]).substring(1);
    }
      }
}
```

So I got n value on my var and that's it. thanks Anyway =D

Comment: If you return something, the other statements after it will never be executed. Moreover, it is a good practice to define the return type of a function.

Comment: I forgot to remove that line "arr[n]= String(arr[n]).substring(1);" in my code im not using that line since I add a return.